# Yeoman angular build process issue

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am getting this error which I am unable to interprete correctly.
Can somebody give me a good hint.
Thanks a lot
Peter

```
     Warning: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined


Execution Time (2015-11-29 16:40:32 UTC)
loading tasks                   387ms  ▇▇▇▇ 12%
loading grunt-contrib-imagemin   2.6s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 79%
imagemin:dist                   288ms  ▇▇▇ 9%
Total 3.3s Used --force, continuing.

Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined
```

Comment: what trace please? I run grunt as command with the --force. I portion of the grunt init for images is like imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    }

Comment: a Stack Trace for the error. Maybe try running with `grunt --verbose` for more details. Right now I can't help you because I have no context at all, this error could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error.
In my case it helped doing:

```
sudo npm cache clean && npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin
```

Answer (score 2):

Try updating "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0" in your package.json.
More info here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/325